# extracting link from a string containing html and javascript

Tags: php, html

I have a string that contains the following:

```
<img data-bind="defaultSrc: {srcDesktop: 'http://desktoplink', srcMobile: 'http://mobilelink', fallback: 'http://baseurl'}" >
```

I am trying to extract the `srcDesktop` contained inside the string. I want my final result to yield me with the link `http://desktoplink`. What is the best way to achieve that other than `str_replace`? I have a dataset that contains those strings so I am looking for a formula to extract it in php.

Here is how I have been doing it, but there is got to be a more efficient way:

```
$string = '<img data-bind="defaultSrc: {srcDesktop: \'http://desktoplink\', srcMobile: \'http://mobilelink\', fallback: \'http://baseurl\'}" >';
$test = explode(" ",$string);
echo "<br>".str_replace(",","",str_replace("'","",$test['3']));
```

Comment: Your string is invalid; it will read `"<img data-bind="` and then throw a syntax error. You need to escape your quotation marks.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I will fix.. just noticed that

Comment: @shnisaka I have updated my answer. Added "i" modificator for case insensitivity and \b to determine srcDesktop left word boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_match

```
$string = '<img data-bind="defaultSrc: {srcDesktop: \'http://desktoplink\', srcMobile: \'http://mobilelink\', fallback: \'http://baseurl\'}" >';

preg_match('/.*\bsrcDesktop:\s*(?:\'|\")(.*?)(?:\'|\").*/i', $string, $matches);

if (isset($matches[1])) {
    echo trim($matches[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use DOMDocument and json_decode to get this value, if you can change the code to the code below (added some '-signs):

```
$string = "<img data-bind=\"'defaultSrc': {'srcDesktop': 'http://desktoplink', 'srcMobile': 'http://mobilelink', 'fallback': 'http://baseurl'}\" >";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
$data = str_replace('\'','"',$doc->getElementsByTagName('img')[0]->getAttribute('data-bind'));
$json = json_decode('{'.$data.'}');
var_dump($json->defaultSrc->srcDesktop);
```

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in test.php on line 7
NULL

Comment: @shnisaka my bad. Fixed it. I missed the missing quotes at srcMobile and fallback. Is it an option for you to add them? I build json compatible syntax from your code... it would be better if you save a json string instead of something that looks a little bit like json. Then it's a little bit simpler ;)

Comment: your code is working now. Thank you for your contribution.. the method I am using is pulling faster at the moment. But I am willing to see other ideas. Yours is much more organized and can pull whatever you want with few changes.

Comment: @shnisaka yes. And it's tougher (safer). It will also work if there are more spaces or if srcDesktop is not the first noted key. What happens in your code if the url contains a comma? (it's valid in urls) You're perhaps changing the urls in the way you chose. and so on.